# How to keep the address stored in a pointer passed as an argument consistent across all function calls

Tags: c++, function, c++11, pointers, parameter-passing

I can pass any argument by reference and the changes to that variable in any of the function calls are reflected in other function calls too.

Likewise if I want to keep the address stored in a pointer consistent across all the function call such that it behaves like we are passing a pointer by reference.

Comment: So? Pass the pointer by reference?

Comment: Please provide a code snippet that illustrates your question, instead of describing it in words.

Comment: Hmm, address of argument passed by reference always consistant. It's same memory location. It's not clear what do you ask. If you have to change the adress inside of function (dubious architecture to say at least), pass pointer by reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass pointers by reference too, as suggested in a comment.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
void f(int * & p) {
  std::cout << p << std::endl;
}
int main() {
  int x;
  int * p = &x;
  std::cout << p << std::endl; // This prints the same...
  f(p);                        // ... as this.
}
```